# Installing a 10.10 package on a 10.04 LTS

Tags: 10.04, package-management

While trying to install rubygems 1.3.7 from the Maverick [repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/all/rubygems1.8/download) (Lucis has 1.3.5) I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Breaks existing package 'rubygems' dependency rubygems1.8 (= 1.3.5-1ubuntu2)
```

Is there a way to override this, even though it may not be recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `ppa:maco.m/ruby` PPA

Another option is to build it from source (using instruction from [here](http://castilho.biz/blog/2010/05/08/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/)):

```
sudo su
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install ruby rdoc libopenssl-ruby
wget http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.3.7.tgz
tar zxvf rubygems-1.3.7.tgz
cd rubygems-1.3.7
ruby setup.rb
ln -s /usr/bin/gem1.8 /usr/local/bin/gem
```